# How to stop page propagation and show a custom pop up in page unload event

Tags: javascript

When I have unsaved changes in a page, and user tries to navigate away from the page I want to show a custom pop up to the user instead of IE's default confirmation pop up in "unload" method of the page. But I am not able to stop the propagation of the page in the unload event.I have tried preventdefault() and stoppropagation(), cancelbubble() also, but nothing helped me.

```
 $(window).bind('unload',function () {
//how to stop the page from unloading and show the custom pop up
}
```

Please suggest.Thank You.

Comment: Use `beforeunload` instead, and return string you want show to user.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the user can bypass whatever `JavaScript` in his/hers browser, and alter its content. The unload function is triggered (and will trigger) inside the browser, to indicate the the process (that window) is terminating. It should not be cancelable. As GingerPlusPlus stated, use another function.